# Should we use a capital letter when editing for packages name?

Tags: discussion, editing

When editing a post it is rather common to find something like: "hyperref creates a problem" as title of the question or (concrete example from the list of newest questions) "[latexdiff and lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136786/31058)". Should we add a capital letter if the package name is the first word of the title (or more generally a sentence)? For the visual consistency I would say yes we should, but on the other hand it might be better to stick to the real way of writing the name of the package, so that is why I am referring to the specialists here.

Comment: Not mandatory to edit for every Q with a Captial letter for package, but can be done once a while when the Q is on the front page roll (without bumping the queue). Related [Previous editing and etiquette discussions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3802/15717) and Linked Q's

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would add something like "Package" or "Class" to use the correct call with `\usepackage` or `\documentclass`.

To change only the first letter of a heading to an capital letter is no good practice. Do it only if the post needs improvement too or has to be retagged.

Comment: Could also recast as something like “Using latexdiff and lstlisting together” (well, if that were the question), which IMO is a better title anyway.